# How can I get my renders to look more like what I see in my viewing window?

Tags: texturing, eevee-render-engine, reflection

I have a character animation I'm trying to render.  When I'm working on it in the main viewing window, it looks like this:

[image]

To me, this looks great.  The water looks just like I want it to.  When I render it, however, this is what I get:

[image]

Now the water is washed out and plastic.  The metal parts are also wrong; they look more like ceramic than metal.  Very little of the reflection is coming through.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are not exactly doing something wrong, but to me it looks like the first one is _Material Preview_. Unless you enabled _Scene Lights_ and _Scene World_ in the viewport shading options, the _Material Preview_ uses a default HDRI to light the scene. In the second image it looks like the lighting is very different. Of course the lighting makes a big difference on how things look like. The _Material Preview_ uses _Eevee_ for display, so if you want the render to look like the preview, you should enable _Scene Lights_ and _Scene World_, this way they should be mostly the same.

Comment: Of course if the _Material Preview_ looks better because it has a better environment lighting, then using scene lights/world will make it look less good (= like the render, not the other way round). However the problem  is not that the render quality is worse than preview per se, it is a matter of not having a good lighting / environment setup for it to look better. You could as well disable _Scene Lights/World_ in rendered view to make it look like the better _Material Preview_, however this will only work in the viewport. If you hit F12 to render it will always use the scene lights/world.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I just figured it out.  It's in the View menu, and you can select Viewport Render Animation.  It is ridiculous how I didn't know that.